# submit input in text area using return without inserting a newline character

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I have a binding for a textarea input in Shiny [here](https://github.com/vnijs/radiant/blob/master/inst/base/www/js/returnTextAreaBinding.js). To submit the text entered press CTRL-return (CMD-return on Mac). I would prefer the text be submitted on pressing return (i.e., without CTRL or CMD) but **without** creating a newline. Is this possible? Note: A textarea, rather than a textinput, is needed to provide enough space for input without some of the text being hidden.

EDIT: The binding works with CTRL-return (or CMD-return). On lines 18-22 I can use just `event.keyCode == 13` and that submits the input *but* a newline character is also inserted in the textarea. It is that last part (i.e., the newline) I would like to avoid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should prevent default behavior, which is inserting a new line, before calling your function.

```
if (event.keyCode == 13 && (event.metaKey || event.ctrlKey)) {
    event.preventDefault();
    ...
}
```

Comment: I don't need the metaKey || ctrlKey any more now but other than that this exactly what I was looking for. Thank you @KhaledMohamedP!

Answer (score 0):

Your if statements at lines 28 and 30 need curly braces around the conditional parts.

Not sure, but this might be causing some issues...

Comment: The binding works with CTRL-return (or CMD-return). I can use just `event.keyCode == 13` and that submits the input *but* a newline character is also inserted in the textarea. It is that last part (i.e., the newline) I would like to avoid. I updated my question to clarify that the focus is on lines 18-22.